# How to apply the action to several Outlook items selected?

Tags: vba, outlook

The code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176426%28v=office.12%29.aspx) works for one item only. How to modify that to run `DisplayItemMetadata` (see the code) for each item selected?

Upd. tried to do the following:

```
For Each individualItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    With objButton
        .BeginGroup = True
        .Caption = "My &item"
        .FaceId = 1000
        .Tag = "DisplayItemMetadata"
        If Not IsNull(Selection.Item(1)) Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            ' Just in case the item selected
            ' doesn't have a valid EntryID.
            ' .Parameter = Selection.Item(1).EntryID
            .Parameter = individualItem.EntryID
            On Error GoTo ErrRoutine
        End If
        .OnAction = _
            "Project1.ThisOutlookSession.DisplayItemMetadata"
    End With

Next individualItem
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to iterate over the Selection object, as follows:

```
Dim individualItem As Object
For Each individualItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    'Perform some action on individualItem
Next Message
```

If you have a function that performs an action on a single selected item, then you should change that function to take a parameter (the item to perform the action on) and then call that function inside the above loop.

Comment: @Alain, btw, looks like it is not enough. There is also EntryID used - I need to pass that somehow to DisplayItemMetadata.

Comment: In the routine you linked to, they get that value by going: `Selection.Item(1).EntryID`. Since your selection items are represented by `individualItem`, you just need to replace that line by `individualItem.EntryID`

Comment: @Alain, please have a look at the code I've added to the initial question - it doesn't work as expected - DisplayItemMetadata is still run only once.

Comment: You've ended the loop to soon. Note that there's no function call in that loop anywhere. All you've done is set properties on each selected item. If you want DisplayItemMetaData to run for each one you need to put that function call **inside** the loop.

Comment: @Alain, ok, I've implemented that - I don't use `.Parameter` and get `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` directly at `Sub DisplayItemMetadata()`. Not sure if that can cause some problems.